# Getting error "This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support"

Tags: c#

> This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.

This error occurs when I am trying to get the information from our smsgatwaye site.

The code is as follows:

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR1.0.3705;)");
 string baseurl = "http://smsoutbox.in/?user=test&password=test@123";
 Stream data = client.OpenRead(baseurl);
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
 string s = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
 data.Close();
 reader.Close();
```

I am requesting to  http://smsoutbox.in page which ask for username & password if it is valid than it shows my gateway balance on same page in frame.

But when I get the response, I found this error:

> This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support. (Line) instead of balance in response stream.

How can solve this?

Comment: What it implies there is some different page serving the content, maybe you gotta catch hold of that url

Comment: yes, the balance is displayed in  Send%20Text%20Message.htm page but i can get the source code of that page.

Answer (score 1):

View the source of the page yourself, and look at the frames being used. Open each one separately to determine which URL you need to retreive.

Comment: The Url need to retrive is  http://smsoutbox.in/Send%20Text%20Message.htm, but first i have to request to Http://smsoutbox.in page with userid & password if this is valid than this page shows the balance into Send%20Text%20Message.htm page. than how can i do this?

Comment: What happens if you log on directly to the `Send Text Message.htm` page? And otherwise just login the main page, check if you got a HTTP 200 back (then you're logged in if the server is configured correctly), and you can subsequently request the page to send a message.

Comment: if i directly call the Send Text Message.htm page than it does not show anything because to show the balance user name & password is required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that WebClient already submits a UserAgent and by adding another "user-agent"-header you're not replacing the original header.

Use this modified WebClient that internally uses `HttpWebRequest`'s `UserAgent` property:

http://codehelp.smartdev.eu/2009/05/08/improve-webclient-by-adding-useragent-and-cookies-to-your-requests/

Alternatively it should work to correctly modify the UserAgent like this:

```
client.Headers["user-agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR1.0.3705;)");
```